Why debugging leads to MetaSpace memory leak in Java?
Debugging a class loaded by a ClassLoader created by a user will cause the class to be referenced by JNI global, and the ClassLoader cannot be uninstalled. Repeating this operation for many times will eventually cause MetaSpace overflow.
The fllow image shows TenantClassLoader is referenced by JNI Global(logwire.products.crm.action.customer.ChangeCustomerOwnerUserAction), Why the ClassLoader is referenced by a Class JNI Global, and how to uninstall the ClassLoader?
enter image description here
I try to break debug when recreate TenantClassLoader, but the old TenantClassLoader still not uninstalled.
There is a minimal reproducible example, but it does not fully reproduce the online scene.
Steps to Reproduce:
Debugging the source code, if I don't add any breakpoints, then the ClassLoader can be properly garbage collected, and the console prints 'ClassLoader count: 0'. However, if I add a debugging breakpoint inside the 'run' method of 'MyTask', after the program runs, the ClassLoader is not garbage collected.
package test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class TestClassLoaderLeaks {

    private static WeakReference<ClassLoader> classLoaderRef = null;

    private static void createClassLoader() throws Exception {
        ClassLoader classLoader = new MyClassLoader(new URL[]{});
        classLoaderRef = new WeakReference<>(classLoader);

        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(MyTask.class.getName(), true, classLoader);
        Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor();
        Runnable runnable = (Runnable) constructor.newInstance();
        runnable.run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        createClassLoader();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            gcAndPrintClassLoaderCount(500);
        }

    }

    private static void gcAndPrintClassLoaderCount(long sleepTime) throws InterruptedException {
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        ClassLoader classLoader = classLoaderRef.get();
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(now + ": ClassLoader : " + classLoader);
    }

    public static class MyClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

        private Class<?> clazz;

        public MyClassLoader(URL[] urls) {
            super(urls);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            if (name.equals(MyTask.class.getName())) {
                if (clazz == null) {
                    String className = MyTask.class.getName();
                    String classPath = className.replace(".", "/") + ".class";
                    ClassLoader classLoader = TestClassLoaderLeaks.class.getClassLoader();
                    try (InputStream resourceAsStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(classPath)) {
                        if (resourceAsStream == null) {
                            throw new FileNotFoundException("File " + classPath + " not found");
                        }
                        ProtectionDomain protectionDomain = new ProtectionDomain(null, null);
                        byte[] bytes = resourceAsStream.readAllBytes();
                        clazz = defineClass(className, bytes, 0, bytes.length, protectionDomain);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
                return clazz;
            } else {
                return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MyTask implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MyClassLoader classLoader = (MyClassLoader) this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            System.out.println("This is ClassLoader: " + classLoader);
        }
    }

}


JDK version:
openjdk version "17.0.10" 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.10+7 (build 17.0.10+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.10+7 (build 17.0.10+7, mixed mode)

Why do I need this classloader for?
I need to frequently hot-load java code written by developers so that they can write java immediately as if they were writing JavaScript without restarting java
This happens only while debugging?
Yes, this only happens when debugging, but if we don't debug, No matter how many ClassLoaders are created and loaded, there has never been a ClassLoader leak.
Debugging tool:
IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1

This happens only while debugging? Only in a specific IDE? Provide a [mre]. How do you try to "uninstall" the classloader when not debugging? Is this an issue when not debugging? Have you tried increasing metaspace?

@aled Yes, this only happens when debugging, I will add a minimal reproducible example, when the objects created using the classes loaded by the ClassLoader are all collected by the gc and are not referenced by the ClassLoader, these classes and ClassLoaders will also be reclaimed by the GC. This is not an issue when not debugging, increasing metaspace can only alleviate this problem, not solve it.

The answer will be that >something< connected to the old classloader is still reachable.  There are many ways this can happen.  My advice would be to just restart ... or use a larger metaspace.

By the way, calling System.gc() is not guaranteed to find all of the garbage.  Or to break weak references for all weakly referenced objects.  And when you throw the debugger into the mix ... that changes the way that various aspects of the JVM behave.

@StephenC Yes, there are many cases that can cause ClassLoader to leak, but after we've dealt with it, what we can't handle at the moment is the debug of ClassLoader GC root pointing to Class JNI Global, but if we don't debug, No matter how many ClassLoaders are created and loaded, there has never been a ClassLoader leak.

Calling gc() and sleep() for this kind of issue is usually a bad practice. This may be a bug of the debugger. Have you tried other debuggers? Or other JDK versions? You haven't mention which ones do you use. Why do you need this classloader for?

@StephenC Yes, calling System.gc() is not guaranteed to find all of the garbage, but the online environment will run for many days, which is plenty of time to get rid of the ClassLoader gc

@aled Calling gc() and sleep()  is just to try to reproducing the scene, maybe there is a bug in Java Debug, I dont know, JDK versions and others infomation I added to question description.

I don't think they would accept this as a bug.  More likely just a "feature".  But anyway, if you think it is a bug and you can reproduce it in a Java version that isn't EOL'd, report it!

I can not reproduce it in a minimal example, but it's inevitable in our online environment, whether it's a bug or not, I  don't understand why it points to JNI Global after debugging and can't be uninstalled.

You still didn’t tell which tool you used for debugging or whether you tried other debuggers.

@Holger I debug the code with IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1, other debugging tools do you mean Eclipse or something else？

Yes, Eclipse, Netbeans, or the command line jdb.

@Holger My guess is that it's probably server-side, so I haven't tried another debugger yet.

Well, debuggers receive a handle for each object they see which allows them to query the object or manipulate it. Your problem looks like a failure to release such a handle, so it seems to me that it could be debugger specific.

@Holger Any temporary resources held by the server should be released when the debug is disconnected. In my case, the GC root of the debugged Class still points to JNI Global even after the debug is disconnected.
